# In JPA OneToOne relationship how to insert only one side of the relation

Tags: java, jpa, ejb-3.0

I want to insert data in one side of the relation

This is my Parent entity

```
public class Parent implements Serializable{   

@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)   

private int id;   

private String pfirstName;   

private String plastName;   

private int parentAge;     

public int getId() {   
return id;   
}   
public void setId(int id) {   
this.id = id;   
}   
public String getPfirstName() {   
return pfirstName;   
}   
public void setPfirstName(String pfirstName) {   
this.pfirstName = pfirstName;   
}   
public String getPlastName() {   
return plastName;   
}   
public void setPlastName(String plastName) {   
this.plastName = plastName;   
}   
public int getParentAge() {   
return parentAge;   
}   
public void setParentAge(int parentAge) {   
this.parentAge= parentAge;   
}   
}
```

This is my Child entity

view plaincopy to clipboardprint?
Note: Text content in the code blocks is automatically word-wrapped

```
public class Child implements Serializable{   
/**  
 *   
 */  
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;   
@Id  
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)   
private int id;   

private String cfirstName;   

private String plastName;   

private int childAge;   

@OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,   
fetch=FetchType.EAGER)   
@JoinColumn(name="pId")   
private Parent parent;   

public int getId() {   
return id;   
}   
public void setId(int id) {   
this.id = id;   
}   
public String getCfirstName() {   
return cfirstName;   
}   
public void setCfirstName(String cfirstName) {   
this.cfirstName = cfirstName;   
}   
public String getClastName() {   
return clastName;   
}   
public void setClastName(String clastName) {   
this.clastName = clastName;   
}    
public int getChildAge() {   
return childAge;   
}   
public void setChildAge(int childAge) {   
this.childAge = childAge;   
}   
public Parent getParent() {
return parent;
}
 public void setParent(Parent parent) {
this.parent = parent;
}


}
```

Remote Interface Implementation

```
 @`enter code here`Stateless  
 @Remote(InformationRemote.class)   
 public class Information implements InformationRemote {   

/**  
 * Default constructor.   
 */  
public Information() {   
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor s   
}   
@PersistenceContext(unitName="JPADB")   
private EntityManager em;     

public String save(Child child) throws Exception   
{   
    System.out.println("First it si coming");   
    em.persist(child);   
    return("sucess");   
}   
}
```

This is My Insertion Class Save method

```
public void save1()   
{   
Parent p =new Parent();   
Child c=new Child();   
InformationRemote bean=doLookup();   
System.out.println("new method coming");   
p.setParentAge(1);   
p.setPfirstName("GOL");   
p.setPlastName("JON");   
c.setCfirstName("jj");   
c.setClastName("gg");   
c.setChildAge(1);   
c.setParent(p);   
try  
 {   
 String res=bean.save(c);   
 }   
    catch(Exception e)   
    {   
        System.out.println("this is a exception"+e);   
    }   
 }
```

When I call Save matheod

MY DATABASE SHOWING RESULT AS

Parent Table In this Id is primary key

id pfirstName parentAge plastName

1      GOL        1       JON

Child Table 
In this Child Table ID is primary key and pid is foreign key which refers to Parent Table Id

id cfirstName childtAge clastName pid

1       jj        1         gg     1

Now I Want to insert only Child Table like below

id cfirstName childtAge clastName pid

1     jj           1        gg     1

2     kk           2        oo     1

How it possible?

Comment: Can you just say you problem very briefly?  seems you post too much code that not related to your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to add a child to an existing parent. So it's quite simple. Since the parent already exists, you get a reference to it, and then you assign the parent to the new child:

```
public void createChild(String firstName, String lastName, int age, int parentId) {
    Parent parent = entityManager.getReference(Parent.class, parentId);
    Child child = new Child();
    child.setFirstName(firstName);
    child.setLastName(lastName);
    child.setAge(age);
    child.setParent(parent);
    entityManager.persist(child);
}
```